# 'The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must...' error when trying to connect to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server

Our admin set up a brand new Windows 2012 R2 server with Visual Studio 2015. When I try to connect to an existing sql server 2008 database (running on a windows 2008 r2 server) from Visual Studio, using <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Connect to database...</kbd>, I can enter all the information, the dialog retrieves the list of databases, <kbd>Test Connection</kbd> works, but when I click <kbd>ok</kbd> I get:

> The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation

Both servers are under the same domain (development) and I am local admin on both of them. My account though is on a different domain that has access to the development domain.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Are they referring to the windows 2012 server or the database server in the message?

Just as a side note, I can connect successfully from another windows 2008 r2 server using the same windows account.

Update: the connection that fails uses windows authentication.

Comment: If you are using Windows authentication, this is possibly an issue with SPN and Kerberos. If you're using SQL authentication, then I'm at a loss.

Comment: Yes, I am using windows authentication. SQL authentication works fine.

Comment: Give this a look. Definitely Kerberos issue, which means you need to either run `SetSPN`, or modify the AD to give SPN permissions to the account that's running the SQL service. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735885.aspx

Comment: @RandolphWest: are you saying that VS 2015 running on Windows 2012 R2 uses Kerberos when I use windows authentication to connect to sql server 2008 (running on windows 2008 R2) instead of NTLM?

Comment: @RandolphWest: What's weird is that I can see the databases, Test Connection is successful but then when I click ok it fails with the message above.

Comment: Could be a domain trust issue then -- ask your domain admin to sort that out. This is definitely a Kerberos issue.

Comment: Both servers are on the same domain. I will let you know if it works after setting the SPN - it might take a while but I will come back here for sure. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [KB3000850](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3000850/november-2014-update-rollup-for-windows-rt-8.1,-windows-8.1,-and-windo), this affects domain-joined Windows 8.1 computers after installing security update **2992611** or update **3000850**.

I added the following value under:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb`

`ProtectionPolicy = 1 (DWORD)`

Now I can connect.

I found some other postings about this:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/04/01/sql-server-system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-error-generating-xml-document/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/47faab6b-d717-4068-bee4-c694811e0066/credential-manager-problems-error-0x80090345?forum=w8itpronetworking

Comment: It appears to have something to do with Read-Only Domain Controllers, according to Pinal's post. Fascinating. Thanks for this find.

Comment: I also had this problem using a Synology DS1813+ as a domain controller, and adding this registry key to my PC fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: This can also be a Windows 10 issue. Adding this registry key fixed it, though!

Comment: This also fixes the error: "error : Problem getting session token from the server. 'Microsoft.Identity Service.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException: Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken" when trying to login to Visual Studio 2017 professional on a domain joined computer. thank you very much.

Comment: while this does fix various issues, I'm not convinced that it's the correct solution. supposedly this causes the master key to be backup locally rather than on the server, which can cause issues. the better solution should be to get the master key to backup on the domain controller, but I don't know what causes it not to be able to. information about this issue can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/dpapi-masterkey-backup-failures